# How do you reflow Highslide so that it stays centered?

Tags: jquery, highslide

I am building a site which has logic to check whether things are expanded, collapsed, added, deleted, etc and when that happens, we get the Highslide expander and call the reflow function.  Something like:

```
//Open Popup
top.hs.htmlExpand(null, {objectType:'iframe',src:url,align:'center'});

$(document).ready(function(){
  //start jquery function
    reflowPopup();
  //end jquery function
});

function reflowPopup() {
  if (top.hs != undefined) {
    var expander = top.hs.getExpander();
    if (expander) {
      expander.reflow();
    }
  }
}
```

This works great, however it centers vertically/horizontally on load, but when reflowed it leaves the top where it initially loaded and expands/collapses the bottom as it is reflowed.  I would like it to be reflowed equally.  So if it is to expand 20px, move up half to stay vertically centered.  What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m sorry, but Highslide has no function for centering the popup after reflow.

Comment: Have there been any updates in regards with this request? :-)